# i have a number and convert the number in the form of decimal using angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript

question Is In  Angular
my question is like I have a number 123456789 without decimal
now I want to convert this number like this 12.3456789
how can I show in the output

> Blockquote

Comment: hey i want this answer soo anyone are here then solve this question

Comment: Try dividing with 1000000

Comment: @Nitheesh the number is not a static its a dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Some logic like this will help.

```js
const num = 123456789;
const strNum = num.toString();
const modifiedNumber = strNum.length > 2 ? Number(`${strNum.substring(0, 2)}.${strNum.substring(2)}`): num;
console.log(modifiedNumber);
```

**Please Note** : `strNum.substring(2)` is same as `strNum.substring(2, strNum.length)`. If the end index is not specified, it will take the length as default end index.